# C# JSON: Deserialize a string in an enum in Web API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, enums

I use this trick in my Web API application. I work with Dto (Data Transfer Objects). A Dto is the JSON representation of my entity.

I don't know how to deal with enum. I like enum and in my database I save all the data in enum value. But when receiving a JSON object I like to receive it with string value.

```
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DocumentType DocumentTypeEnum
    {
        get
        {
            return (DocumentType)Enum.Parse(typeof(DocumentType), DocumentType);
        }
        set
        {
            DocumentType = value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My enum is

```
public enum DocumentType
{
    PI,
    CI,
    DN,
    CN
};
```

Is there an attribute or a better way to force the system to deserialize the JSON string as enum value?

Comment: I confirm this is a duplicate